# AngularJS does not refresh ng-show when using only attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS app, and just noticed that if I use ng-show and ng-click together and don't use function on the controller, then the ng-show is not working as expected.

So I have this:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Controller">
    <div ng-repeat="d in data">
        <button ng-show="showEdit!==d" ng-click="showEdit=d">{{d}}</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

With a controller:

```
function Controller($scope){
    $scope.data=[1,2,3]
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sashee/v6XrK/

And the buttons are disappearing when I click them, and never reappear.

If I change the view to this:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Controller">
    <div ng-repeat="d in data">
        <button ng-show="showEdit!==d" ng-click="show(d)">{{d}}</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the controller:

```
function Controller($scope){
    $scope.data=[1,2,3]

    $scope.show=function(d){
        $scope.showEdit=d;
    }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sashee/UFGv4/

Everything works as expected. I think both versions should do exactly the same, but they aren't. What could be the difference or the explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, `ng-repeat` creates it's own scope, so when you do `showEdit=d` inside your `ng-repeat` -- `showEdit` is limited to the scope of the current repeater. Your variable gets set and your button disappears.

In the example where you call the function, you have a variable `$scope.showEdit` -- well that variable isn't limited to the `repeat` scope, so you will always have two buttons showing since `showEdit` is being assigned differently due to each click.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I haven't thought that they are in different scopes. Now it's all clear

Answer (score 0):

Please use spaces in your angular expressions.

The difference is that your ng-show and ng-click are in an ng-repeat.  Each ng-repeat element has its own scope.  So when you do the following:

ng-click="showEdit=d"

You are creating a new value of showEdit on the anonymous ng-repeat scope, not the scope that your controller knows about.  Other ng-repeat elements know nothing about it, so your conditional ng-show="showEdit!==d" reflects the value that you just set, not the value of showEdit from your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's a bit quirky.

`ng-repeat` creates a **new scope** for each iterated element.

When you bind the click expression `showEdit=d`, you actually bind this expression to the **Nth** scope, created by the `ng-repeat` (hence the `showEdit` is located in `scopeN`).

When you simply use the function from the Controller, you change the `showEdit` field of the **Controller's** scope!

```
- Controller scope (showEdit in the 2nd example)
  - scope 1 (showEdit 1 in the 1st example)
  - scope 2 (showEdit 2 in the 1st example)
  ... 
  - scope N (showEdit N in the 1st example)
```